# Nested HTML tables error, missing table near page break in print preview IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, printing, html-table

At the business I work at we generate reports in an html format, our clients often print these reports. The problem we've run into is that sometimes when the clients print, one of the inside tables will start 1 or 2 pixels before the page break in the print view. This causes the table to disappear but the space to be taken up.

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      td { border:1px solid black;}
      table {border-collapse:collapse;}
    </style>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <TABLE class="main">
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <TABLE class="second">
            <TR>
              <TD style="border-top:824px solid-black">1</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD>1_1</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD>1_2</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD>1_3</TD>
            </TR>
          </TABLE>
        </TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <TABLE class="second">
            <TR>
                  <TD>2</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD>2_1</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD>2_2</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD>2_3</TD>
            </TR>
          </TABLE>
        </TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <TABLE class="second">
            <TR>
              <TD>3</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD>3_1</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD>3_2</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD>3_3</TD>
            </TR>
          </TABLE>
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The code above should reproduce the error, but you may have to add some padding on the border to bump the second table to just before the page break.

we've tried page breaks, padding, border collapse, no border collapse. The error appears to persist when it's just the two tables without any styling aside from the border of the cells. This appears to be a rather large defect, but I've had very little luck finding anything at all about it.

Is this a problem with IE or is there something we can do to get around this issue?

**EDIT**
We tried with as bare bones as possible (only borders on the TD elements) and we were encountering the same issues.

We were unable to solve the problem, but our work around consisted of using only once cell of the outer table and putting each of the inner tables inside there. This prevented the tables from disappearing near the page breaks.

Comment: it turns out that even without border collapse we can still replicate the problem

Comment: What sort of crazy data structure do you have that justifies nested tables? (Or are they unjustified layout tables?)

Comment: CSS styles like `page-break-after` also don't work well within tables. You really should try finding a solution without the big outer table.

Comment: Generating PDF files from your HTML server-side is far more dependable than depending on the browser to print things properly.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the exact same problem with IE7 and IE8 in our business application which uses a nested table layout.
Internet Explorer 11 does not have this problem as per our testing evidence for the affected samples.

This is a bug in IE which exists in pre-IE 10 versions as per Microsoft Technical Support, and is reflected also in the Print-to-PDF functionality used by many PDF printers which is how we first located the bug.

Unfortunately I cannot provide any evidence of what I stated. Kindly check in IE11 and confirm if it solved your issue. The other alternative would be to test it out with div-based layout, if you're not willing to switch browsers yet.